# How do I create alias below documentroot in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, alias

I'm trying to create a bin folder accessible to a virutalhost beneath the document root.

I currently access the folder through mysite.local/bin, but need the files to be beneath public access.

httpd.conf

```
Alias /bin/ "C:/wamp/www/bin/"

<Directory "bin">
  AllowOverride None
  Options None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName   mysite.local
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/mysite.com/html"
</VirtualHost>
```

Theoretically the file tree should read

```
/mysite.com
    /html <-- where mysite.com reads from
    /bin
    /other private folders
```

That way the file in url: mysite.com actual path: mysite.com/html/index.php could read something like this:

```
<?php include "../bin/privatefile.php"; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question, but the following information may help.

If you are trying to configure the directory for the virtual host, then you should put that configuration inside the `<VirtualHost>` directive, not in httpd.conf.

Your `<Directory>` directive is incorrect:  [`<Directory>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) takes a *directory-path* parameter.  You supplied a *url-path* parameter, which would be suitable for a [`<Location>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) directive.  `<Directory>` and `<Location>` are very similar with the main difference being whether the argument is a directory path or a url path.

The document ["Mapping URLs to Filesystem Locations"](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html) may also prove helpful.

---

In the directory tree you diagrammed, `bin/` is *above* `html/`, not below.

You do not need the Alias or the Directory directives at all.  The path in the PHP include directive is a filesystem path, not a URL path.  I just tested it to verify since I'm not that fluent in PHP.

Comment: I believe you're on the right track and that's where I am currently at. I updated the post to reflect the file tree.

Comment: I updated my answer to correspond to the new information in your question.